# Why can't paste into BrowserStack browser?

Tags: copy-paste, browserstack

I'm just trying to paste a URL from my clipboard into browserstack, but it won't paste.

[This](https://www.browserstack.com/question/489) mentions when you aren't supposed to be able to:

> You cannot copy from remote browsers to your browser: In Firefox and
>   Chrome, if the BrowserStack extension is not installed.

I do have "BrowserStack Local" installed, but it didn't work. I have tried copying the url from a text document, not a browser, and it still wouldn't let me paste it into BrowserStack browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you want to install the main "BrowserStack" extension.

But a workaround that worked for me without the extension:

Paste what you have copied in your clipboard into your browser's address bar (the tab that you have Browserstack open with). Then Copy it again out of the address bar.

You should now be able to scroll down and paste it into Browserstack's virtual browser as per usual.